# Can we use gauge/gage in Ionic ? (Cordova)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, svg, ionic-framework, gauge

This is my first post here, so I'm sorry if I'm not in the good section.

My "simple" question is, can we add a gage/gauge (I don't now the exact english spelling), in a Ionic project ?

A thing like that:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2qrYL0Le24

Or an other exemple:

http://crisbeto.github.io/angular-svg-round-progressbar/

I already tried to insert gauge like that in my project but the gauge never appears, so please, can you help me ?

(The goal is to show to an user a speed for exemple or the batterie life of his smartphone, any importance, juste a jauge who can be incremented or decremented)

Can you explain me please how it works, for example via a Codepen or anything else. I had already tried to search response but I solve anything on that.

I'm french and I am sorry for my language, but thanks in advance for you'r help !

Thanks.

Comment: every thing is clear in that github link,what your not understanding in that??

Comment: I already tried to follow the instruction to use gauge but my app show a blank screen or the bar not appears, I have no error in the console. Did you used it in a Cordova Ionic App ?

Comment: I seen you'r an expert in angularJS and etc, did you have an exemple of a project how integrate gauge like I said ? Thank you very much for you'r help.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/BenBBear/ionic-cache-src-demo/tree/master/www/lib/angular-svg-round-progressbar  I follow the instructions, but when I add the module 'angular-svg-round-progress' in var app = angular.module('myChartApp', ['ionic', 'chart.js']); like that: var app = angular.module('myChartApp', ['ionic', 'chart.js', 'angular-svg-round-progress' ]); The app displays a grey screen and in the console there is 6 error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work:
https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-gage

You must also have the JustGage library and Raphael. Take a look at the example to see it in action. I was able to even make it work in the http://creator.ionic.io app by adding the scripts of angular-gage, JustGage and Raphael (just add a js and paste in the scripts).

Comment: Hello, I already tried to use Justgage without succes, by with no error in the console, did you saved you'r project ? Can you share it please ? Or give me an exemple (Codepen.io), if you are able to do it working please. I did search about it but I solve anything. Thank you so much for you'r answer (This is my school poject and it's very important for me :/ )

Comment: Not sure if you understand. Follow the example in angualuar-gage. Here is my example. https://creator.ionic.io/share/65bb5748efbe

Comment: How can I use that in Ionic: https://github.com/BenBBear/ionic-cache-src-demo/tree/master/www/lib/angular-svg-round-progressbar Can you show me an example please (like the one you've created) ? I seen you'r app but I prefer a complete round bar like that https://github.com/BenBBear/ionic-cache-src-demo/tree/master/www/lib/angular-svg-round-progressbar Thank you so much for you'r help

Comment: that would be a different question. Please up vote my answer if it answers original question and create a new question for the above.

Comment: Hello, thank you for you'r response, but I research an exemple of a full circle gauge, like that: https://github.com/BenBBear/ionic-cache-src-demo/tree/master/www/lib/angular-svg-round-progressbar or like the YT link I posted 2 days ago. Thanks in advance.